# Pending gitlab-ci test job using gradle and kotlin

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to build a kotlin library using gradle (wrapped) and gitlab-ci. If i execute commands on my machine everything works fine but gitlab-ci test job doesnt not end and is pending on `Task :test`.

I'm using basic gitlab-ci inspired by [this example](https://gist.github.com/daicham/5ac8461b8b49385244aa0977638c3420).

```
image: gradle:5.6.2-jdk8

stages:
  - build
  - test

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle

cache:
  paths:
    - .gradle/wrapper
    - .gradle/caches

build-latest:
  stage: build

  script:
    - ./gradlew assemble

  only:
    - master
    - tags

test:
  stage: test

  script:
    - ./gradlew check
```

and that's gitlab-ci ( 12.2.5 ) output

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.2.0 (a987417a)
  on autoscale-runner eaccdfe9
Using Docker executor with image gradle:5.6.2-jdk8 ...
Pulling docker image gradle:5.6.2-jdk8 ...
Using docker image sha256:5eacc675d8626e3db6a6c4030fc817113f536f565ecd23b7f5aec7e5e5bfcc53 for gradle:5.6.2-jdk8 ...
Running on runner-eaccdfe9-project-769-concurrent-0 via runner-eaccdfe9-autoscale-1570629641-a91eb9db...
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/platform/libraries/kafka2rest/.git/
Checking out 69a3b20e as master...
Removing .gradle/
Removing build/

Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for default-1...
Downloading cache.zip from http://10.164.0.3:9000/runner/runner/eaccdfe9/project/769/default-1 
Successfully extracted cache
$ export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
$ ./gradlew -v

Welcome to Gradle 5.6.2!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Incremental Groovy compilation
 - Groovy compile avoidance
 - Test fixtures for Java projects
 - Manage plugin versions via settings script

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/release-notes.html


------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.6.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-09-05 16:13:54 UTC
Revision:     55a5e53d855db8fc7b0e494412fc624051a8e781

Kotlin:       1.3.41
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.14 compiled on March 12 2019
JVM:          1.8.0_222 (AdoptOpenJDK 25.222-b10)
OS:           Linux 4.15.0-1044-gcp amd64

$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_222-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
$ ./gradlew check
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :compileKotlin
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes

> Task :compileTestKotlin

> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test
```

What's wrong with this? Is there any standard or template for building kotlin with gradle and gitlab-ci?

**Edit**
I've found the pending test suite. It contains 3 test, any of them create new instance of controller that has the same `start()` method. The `start()` method launch a new thread. If just one test runs it works with successful gitlab-ci termination, if two or more test run it doesn't and it remains in pending state. In tests I use semaphores.
Tests still work locally.

Comment: Do you have any [`readLine`s](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/read-line.html) (or `System.in` or similar) in your test? Or, in general, any kind of interactive logic? Is it possible that under some conditions (missing file or environment config) you go into an infinite loop? Any network requests?

Comment: I send some http request to a MockServer (istantiated in tests) (http://www.mock-server.com/)

Comment: How do you start it? If you start in in the same thread your tests run, your test... would never run as it will occupy it. You should either make sure you start it in a separate thread or use GitLab's services. The idea is that it should run in parallel with your tests.

Comment: I found the pending test suite. It contains 3 test, any of them instances a controller that launch the same `start()` method. The`start()` method launch a new thread.
If just one test runs it works with successful gitlab-ci termination, if two or more test run it doesn't and remain in pending state.

Comment: Cleaning gitlab cache with `Clear Runner Caches` it terminates with success. Sometimes.